# solr is not showing response of re-indexed document

Tags: indexing, solr

**what I am doing**

- I am following a tutorial of solr and training on exampledocs folder

**where i am getting issue**

- I inserted all the documents in exampledocs folder and got result in query
- But when i made a change to a field and re inserted one document, i am unable to get the result.(document got inserted successful)

**Information Required**

- I had not changed any configuration files, i am just following a tutorial
- In tutorial he is getting the answer but i am not getting.
- i am using solr version 4.9.1

after insert i did "optimize" and "reload" in "core admin" page, but still i am not getting the changes. ('Windows7 64bit' is my pc)

please help.  (i can provide any info )

Comment: Why are you using a very outdated version of Solr? A lot has changed since 4.9.1. What exactly are the requests you're trying? How are you confirming that everything is OK? Are you updating a single field with an atomic update, or are you sending the complete document each time?

Comment: what tutorial you are following. ? if you changed a field and reindexed document successfully. it should not create any problems.

Comment: @MatsLindh  hello, my company is using old version, so i have to practice it. I am trying to update the information of a field in a document. For that I am always sending complete document. when i do it is not showing the document but number of documents are same.

Comment: @vinod I am folllowing pluralsight tutorial of solr which my compant had given to me to practice. The problem is it is not showing the document at all. If i give all 10 documents at a time then my changes in one document is done.

Comment: Are you supplying the same value in the uniqueKey/id field of the documents?

Comment: @ MatsLindh yes i am giving same id.  Yesterday i checked with linux, it is working in linux but problem still persist on windows.